# Spring Boot doesn't scan packages

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

This is my project structure: [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rghfw.png)

Whenever i try to run application it fails with this error:

Field sectionDAO in com.klag.forum.Service.SectionServiceimpl required a bean of type 'com.klag.forum.dao.SectionDAO' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.klag.forum.dao.SectionDAO' in your configuration.

The solution I found to this problem is adding ComponentScan with com.klag.forum.dao .

It worked until I found out there is a problem with scanning controllers too.
So i tried to add another path to scan controllers, but then the errors comes back. It works only with this configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.klag.forum.dao")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.klag.forum.dao")
@EntityScan("com.klag.forum.Entity")
```

It doesnt work after adding another path like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.klag.forum.dao",com.klagu.forum.controller})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.klag.forum.dao")
@EntityScan("com.klag.forum.Entity")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't... Put the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in the `com.klag.forum` package and remove all other annotations. This is the advice that the Spring Boot team gives. Also make sure (judging from the `ServletInitializer` that that class extends the proper classes. Also why are your packaged named with upper-case letters? The names in your annotations don't match your actual package name.

Comment: So where should i put it?

Comment: Scanning from forum doesnt work.

Comment: You should only have the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation remove all other annotations. I assume you are just running the application and not deploying it as a war. Although the `ServletInitializer` makes me wonder...

Comment: ServletInitialize was created by default using Intelij

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `@SpringBootApplication` to your `ForumApplication` class.

All the annotation in child packages will be scanned

Comment: Thats what i did.

Comment: Remove all other annotation, just `@SpringBootApplication` is enough

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this problem was missing @Repository annotations in dao's. 
Thank you for your help.